# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "driver" is null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

I'm having a few troubles working with Selenium and the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/). So the WebDriverManager documentations says that you're able to create a WebDriver with their API as descirbed [here](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#webdriver-builder). Unfortunately I'm also not able to init the driver with `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` since then I encounter an `SessionNotCreatedException`.

Code:

```
package test;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Main {
static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  driver = WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().create();
  driver.get("google.com");
  driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "driver" is null
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Setup:

- OS: Windows 10
- Browser: Firefox 102
- Driver: Gecko 0.31.0
- Selenium: 4.3.0
- WebDriverManager: 5.2.1

Comment: seems like you're missing Selenium itself... and the import of: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the driver is dead
instead of using this
"driver = WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().create();"
can you please try this
" WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing your driver like this?

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
  "src/test/resources/Driver/geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Import, instead of TestNG annotations you may be given JUnit.

Before :

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
```

After :

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
```